# The <service> MyFirebaseInstanceIdService is not registered in the manifest

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-manifest

I am using the service of **FirebaseInstanceIdService** to get the refreshed token. 
However it never called and always has the warning of

> The  MyFirebaseInstanceIdService is not registered in the
>   manifest

- **FirebaseInstanceIdService**

public class MyFirebaseInstanceIdService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {

```
@Override
public void onTokenRefresh() {
    // Get updated InstanceID token.
    String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
    Timber.d("Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);
}
```

}

- **Manifest**

  ```
  <service
      android:name="MyFirebaseInstanceIdService"
      android:enabled="true"
      android:exported="false">
      <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
      </intent-filter>
  </service>
  <service
      android:name="com.arts.m3droid.samatravel.empl.MyMessageService"
      android:enabled="true"
      android:exported="false">
      <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
      </intent-filter>
  </service>
  ```

I added the service to manifest using the documentation from firebase and also by using create a new Service ( File > New > Service > Service ) in Android studio.

Comment: The issue is that default package doesn't work in this case. You can add your class to a package and then specify the package in the service tag.

Comment: Yup, that was it thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I Hope this will work for you.

Create MyFirebaseInstanceIdService in your package.

```
    public class MyFirebaseInstanceIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {

        private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseIIDService";

        @Override
        public void onTokenRefresh() {
            String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
            Log.e(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);
            storeToken(refreshedToken);
        }

        private void storeToken(String token) {
           //Store your token in sharedpreference.
        }
    }
```

and call like this in Manifest.

```
<service android:name=".MyFirebaseInstanceIDService">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
                </intent-filter>
            </service>
```

Answer (score 1):

Update your manifest to specify the full package name for your service class, for example:

```
android:name="com.arts.m3droid.samatravel.empl.MyFirebaseInstanceIdService"
```

You can also use '.' for the application package name, as is [shown in the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client#manifest):

```
android:name=".MyFirebaseInstanceIdService"
```

See also the [documentation for Service name](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/service-element):

> The name of the Service subclass that implements the service. This
>   should be a fully qualified class name (such as,
>   "com.example.project.RoomService"). However, as a shorthand, if the
>   first character of the name is a period (for example, ".RoomService"),
>   it is appended to the package name specified in the 
>   element.